# Xml-разметка вкладки

Tags: xml, android, java

Есть приложение с двумя вкладками.
Для первой сделал разметку, ко второй не знаю ка перейти.
Нужно сделать xml разметку еще и для нее.

Код:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dip" >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                                android:layout_width="80dip"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:text="20" >

                                <requestFocus />
                            </EditText>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="5" >

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/arrow"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/arrow"
                                    android:text="@string/textView2"
                                    android:textColor="#b1cc47" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dip" >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                                android:layout_width="80dip"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:text="9313" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="5" >

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/arrow"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/arrow"
                                    android:text="@string/textView1"
                                    android:textColor="#b1cc47" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:baselineAligned="true" >

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/button2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/button2" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/button1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:maxHeight="10dip"
                                android:src="@drawable/ok" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: минус за такой длинный код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так будет очень неудобно работать!!!

"Разделяй и властвуй" :)

Простейший пример [тут](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/android-tab-bar-example-1/)